# Do diff between pairs of a file a list

Tags: linux, shell, unix, loops

I have a directory on my Linux system whose contents are file names in pairs as follows:

```
 File1a
 File1b
 File2a
 File2b
 File3a
 File3b
```

I want to do a diff between the contents of File1a and File1b and store the results in a separate file. Similarly do this over other pairs iterating through the entire list. Can this be achieved with a shell script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to rely on what's inside your file because your filenames do not match the simple pattern that you posted (and your filenames don't contain spaces) you can do something like:

```
xargs -L2 echo < file.txt | while read first second; do
    diff "${first}" "${second}" > "${first}_${second}.diff"
done
```

Otherwise go for @devnull's or @mbratch's solution.

Comment: Adrian..this worked..my file names were not of the exact pattern that i posed in the question..only your method worked..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in 1 2 3
do
  diff File${x}a File${x}b > File${x}diff
done
```

This will put each diff into its own file (`File1diff` for example). If you want all the diffs into one file, you could do this:

```
for x in 1 2 3
do
  echo "***** Diff of File${x}a <> File${x}b:" >> DiffOutput
  diff File${x}a File${x}b >> DiffOutput
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming filenames are of form `File\d*{a,b}`:

```
for i in File*a; do
  diff ${i} ${i%a}b > ${i%a}.diff
done
```

The diff would be redirected to `File1.diff` for a pair `File1a` & `File1b`.