# gnudiff, and .gitignore files

Tags: git, diff, gitignore

To be clear - This is not a `git diff` problem or question

I have two locally checked out repos - that share a common quasi common heritage.

Both are under git control (but come from two separate remote servers) - they have many things in common.

What I would like to do is a normal gnu `diff -Naur` type comparison between the two directory structures.

Normally you would use `--exclude=PATTERN` options for gnu-diff to exclude things.  For example you might `--exclude=.git` to ignore the two different *.git* directories

What I want instead is an option to make gnu-diff *.gitignore* aware

in effect, as gnu diff traverses the directory structure and comes across a *.gitignore* file follow the GIT rules and ignore accordingly.

Sort of an option like this:

```
diff -Naur  --honor-git-ignore-files  DIR1   DIR2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be a default linux diff option like the one you mention, you could:

- [list all not ignored files with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39064584/6309) (at least using [`git ls-files --exclude-standard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#git-ls-files---exclude-standard)) in both Git repos,
- select the common files between the two
- [apply a diff for each common file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18467483/6309)

Comment: Hmm - that may well work - let me experiment. A little shell script magic might simplify some of this.

Comment: @user3696153 Did you find the bit of "shell script magic" for this?